# Tools for load-testing a videoserver

Tags: video, streaming, load-testing, rtsp

I'm looking for a tool capable of setting up multiple RTSP streaming sessions and keeping them alive for a configurable amount of time. Ideally this should not be videoserver specific and as lightweight as possible. The only tools I know of are

- [OpenRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/)
- running VLC in headless mode

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: For the same task we used vlc in the form of standalone app as well as activex plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure `mplayer` can be used as a RTSP client. You can use `-ss` option to force it to fast forward to provided position and `-endpos` for setting how long it has to play. Together with `-vo null -ao null` it won't require X server running or audio card present.